# SQL Server Profiler - How to filter trace to only display TSQL containing a DELETE statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a SQL Trace setup to monitor all TSQL being issued to a single database. However I only care about 'DELETE' TSQL statements being issued. Is there any way I can filter to just reporting these type of statements to the profiler? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When setting up your trace, go to event selection and select only `TSQL->Batch completed`. Now click the `column filters` button and choose `TextData` -> `Like` and write `%delete%`. That should do it.

**EDIT**: Added percent signs (`%`) around `delete` because they are needed to make it work.

Comment: OK did exactly that, but it did not appear to work. Not using the trace properties but if I just go to 'File' -> 'Find' and type in 'delete', search in column 'TextData' it finds the word DELETE in any part of the TSQL. If I add that filter *exactly* as you mentioned (great easy to follow directions, thanks) it does not pick up anything. Added the filter on SQL:BatchCompleted Like ---> delete. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm... instead of just `delete` try `%delete%`

Comment: @atconway Yup... just tried it out. You definitely need the % signs.

Comment: For me I had to have the RPC:Completed row selected, rather than SQL:BatchCompleted as I was looking for a sproc call.