# How to capture truncate statement information in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, truncate, truncate-log

I would like to capture the truncate statements information along with the user/Login information for all database in my production server.

Example:

```
Use mydb
go 
truncate table deleteme_table
```

I would like to capture the information into the table like the below

```
Table           Operation   Database    Login              Time
deleteme_table  Truncate    mydb        sandeep.pulikonda  17-12-2014 17:50:00
```

If the above scenario is not possible please suggest possible ways to capture it

I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard version. So granular level audit are not supported for that version.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't track this information by default. You'll need to use a server-side trace (Profiler is *NOT* "a good way") or use extended events. This information is not captured by the default trace and there is no DDL event to support a DDL trigger approach (though [I just asked for one](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1074977).).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the SQL Server Audit functionality and add an audit for those queries.

[this article explains in detail how to obtain this.](https://sqlship.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/how-to-capture-delete-and-truncate-t-sql-using-database-audit-specification/)

Another good way of profiling your SQL Server is using SQL Profiler. Here is a SO question similar to yours and an answer describing how to use SQL Profiler to achieve the results.

[SQL Server Profiler - How to filter trace to only display TSQL containing a DELETE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903208/sql-server-profiler-how-to-filter-trace-to-only-display-tsql-containing-a-dele)

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard version. So Granular level audit are not supported for that version.

Comment: try my second suggestion, SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: okay. can the tracer capture all times. I mean like table triggers

Comment: unfortunately Profiler does have a performance impact, and is not recommended for permanent use.

Comment: I see that Extended Events is the technology that Microsoft Recommends using for these kinds of tasks, but I am uncertain if you could solve your problem this way. Check this article, it explains how Extended Events can be defined and used in SSMS 2012. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/